# Solve $2x-2yd=y+xd$ for $d$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Solve for $d$

$$2x-2yd=y+xd$$ $$2(x-yd)=y+xd$$ $$2(x-yd)-y=xd$$ $$\frac{2(x-yd)-y}{x}=d$$  Now I think this is wrong considering I have a $d$ on the other side and I would have to reverse my work and end up at the beginning. Any small pointers or tips? Thanks!

Comment: Group all the terms with $d$ in them on one side, and everything else on the other. Factor out the $d$...

Comment: Is it; $\dfrac{2x-y}{x-2y}=d$ ???

Comment: $\dfrac{2x-y}{x + 2y} = d$, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: Oh, right. I wrote the OP wrong in my notebook. Thanks a lot. This was easier than I made it out to be!

Comment: You might consider writing up your work in an answer. Then you can accept your own answer (seems funny, doesn't it!) to indicate that this problem is solved.

Comment: I re-wrote everything like I always do! I'm a good student!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(When I said "... write up your work in an answer", I meant like THIS!)*

$$2x−2yd=y+xd$$
$$2x - y = 2yd + xd$$
$$2x - y = d(2y + x)$$
$$\dfrac{2x-y}{2y+x} = d$$

*(You can formally "accept" any answer by clicking the check mark in the upper left hand corner. If you'd like to wait a few hours/days for a better answer to come along, or write your own, feel free. )*